# is there a Proxy Server which forward to dynamic IP?

Tags: proxy

is there a Proxy Server which forward to dynamic IP?
for example, a proxy server as a center, it chose an proxy server from a pool to forward.

Comment: on what basis would the proxy choose the next proxy to use?  There are several products (our own included) that allow you to choose an upstream proxy based on a number of criteria.

Comment: something like http://scrapoxy.io/